# How to exclude ts files in mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

Does anybody know how to exclude typescript file when run mocha?

```
mocha test/*.js
```

This command doesn't help. Mocha tries to run typescript files.
I need to execute only .js test files.

Comment: That should only pick up javascript files with the extension `.js`. Usually typescript files have an extension of `.ts`.

Comment: Mocha should never run `ts` files anyway. It doesn't understand them.